# Implications of not `then`-ing or `await`-ing asynchronous functions in React/ExpressJS

Tags: reactjs, express

In our React and ExpressJS code we have asynchronous functions that we are invoking but not `then`-ing or `await`-ing. This is deliberately done as they aren't crucial for the code flow and we are optimising for user latency. An example of where we do this is when we send off telemetry or metric data.

What are the potential gotchas that we need to be aware of when doing this? I can think of the following off the top of my head:

- We won't know if that call fails since we don't handle or know about its error (this is fine if it's an intermittent downstream issue)
- Related to the above, we won't know if there's a bug in our actual code
- This one I'm not so sure about but could the async function fail to complete if the main thread is killed (i.e. user navigates to another page, or expressJS server is terminated?)

Are there other gotchas/implications that our team should be aware of?

Are there better patterns in achieving the same result?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only main downside is that you can't handle errors in the main code flow.  You would have to invent some way to handle errors appropriately and to even know about them.

There are some situations where you may want to know about the errors (when developing/debugging) via some sort of logging, but in production code, there's really nothing to do about the errors so you just ignore them.  In other situations, you need some way to communicate errors, even if it's not in the main code flow.

If the user navigates to another page while you have an "in-process" asynchronous operation such as an Ajax call with telemetry data, chances are pretty good that the Ajax call has already been sent and is just waiting for a response which will do no harm.  The data has already been sent.

If the target server is terminated, then the Ajax call will fail (probably quickly) and you'll be back in the first situation above (what to do with errors).

> Are there other gotchas/implications that our team should be aware of?

Just the ones you mention and the consequences of error handling which is specific to the exact situation and code.  If it's no big deal to let the telemetry data get dropped if something goes wrong in the transmission, then you're fine.  If it's vital that it get delivered reliably, then you will need a bunch more code to retry transmission errors, prevent navigating away from the page, etc...  Even then the user can still probably close the browser or the browser window/tab with no guarantees of successful transmission.

> Are there better patterns in achieving the same result?

Generically, no - there is no generic design pattern for this.  We'd really have to see the overall structure of your code, understand the reliability requirements around the transmission of the telemetry data and see the exact transmission code and where it is your code flow to make more specific suggestions.